# linux find file modiffied past exact hour

Tags: linux, find

I would like to find files that are modiffied past exact hour.
example:

```
File             Time Modified             
test1.log             14.45PM   
test2.log             15.01PM            
test3.log             15.15PM
```

So when i run the find fuction at 15.30PM I want it to display only

- test2.log
- test3.log

Currently my code is

```
find /root/Desktop/test/ -type f -mmin -60
```

this will display

- test1.log
- test2.log
- test3.log

I want it to display 15:00PM onwrds file not 1 hour from 15:30 possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `-60` to however many minutes past sharp the time is.

```
find /root/Desktop/test/ -type f -mmin -$(date +%M)
```

The `date` command formats its output based on the current time and the format string `+%M` produces the minutes field of the current time.

Comment: Works like a charm,